# Making a Windows 8.1 laptop communicate with an Android device (4.4.2) over Bluetooth Low Energy?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.4-kitkat

I am new to developing on bluetooth LE stack and need some help understanding a use case and how to make it work.

So, I have a Windows 8.1 Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 2 Pro (with Bluetooth 4.0) and an Android HTC One running KitKat 4.4.2 (also having support for Bluetooth 4.0). The use case I want to accomplish with these resources is to make either one a peripheral and the other one a central device communicating over bluetooth low energy protocol. I read on the android developer website that it doesn't support "peripheral" mode on Android BLE stack yet. And I am fine with that as long as I can get my Win laptop to behave as a peripheral. I am working on an Android client app (so a Master that will request service data from the peripheral/Server). I want to know if Windows 8.1 supports BLE peripheral mode. If so, is there sample code that I can look at. I haven't been able to find info on this yet.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Abhishek